# Fetch JSON data from website using Firebase Functions

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, firebase, google-cloud-functions

This is my database structure:

```
/project-blabla
    /data
        /data-123456: "yes"
```

**My Goal:** When a new string is pushed to **/data**, it gets replaced with an object containing **myObj1 & myObj2** and **myObj3 & myObj4**.

This way, I can display a data by fetching **/data/$dataId/myVar1** and **/data/$dataId/myVar2**.

```
/project-blabla
    /data
        /data-123456
            myVar1: "myObj1 myObj2",
            myVar2: "myObj3 myObj4"
```

I need to get the same result from the following code via firebase functions.

Is it possible? If so, How I do it?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $.ajax({
          url : "http://api.website/MyKey/File.json",
          dataType : "jsonp",
          success : function(parsed_json) {
              var myVar1 = parsed_json['myObj1']['myObj2'];
              var myVar2 = parsed_json['myObj3']['myObj4'];
              alert("Here we go: " + myVar1 + " & " + myVar2);
          }
      });
    });
</script>
```